# Bitwise operations to add two numbers?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

So if I have a number1 and another number2 .. both integers, is my approach corrected in adding two numbers using bitwise operations ? Can this go wrong for any test case ?

```
public int add(int number1, int number2)
{
int carry = (number1&number2)<<1;
int sum = number1^number2^carry;
return sum;
}
```

Comment: If you plug in a few non-trivial numbers, you're realize that it's wrong. Adders need to be chained one after the other. (hint: you need a loop)

Comment: can you give an example of these 2 numbers ?

Comment: `3 + 1` as given in the answer so far. Anything with chained carries will also be wrong, `63 + 1`, `127 + 1`, etc...

Comment: write a unit test and see your self.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. This approach does not work for additions that involve multiple carries. The simplest such case is `3 + 1`; your function gives `0` as a result.

There is no simple general-case solution to solve this -- any solution must take into mind the width of an integer. See [Wikipedia's article on gate-level implementations of addition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_%28electronics%29) for some approaches.

Answer (score 11):

[image: Full Adder]

Here is how an circuit designer would add two numbers. To translate, the two symbols on top with the double curved left edges are XOR (^), the two in the middle with the flat left edges are AND (&), and the last one with the single curved left edge is OR (|).

Now, here's how you could translate that to code, one bit at a time, using a mask.

```
public int add(final int A, final int B) {
    int mask = 1; 
    int sum = 0;
    int carry = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= Integer.SIZE; i++) { //JVM uses 32-bit int
        int a = A & mask; //bit selection
        int b = B & mask;

        //sum uses |= to preserve the history,
        //but carry does not need to, so it uses =
        sum |= a ^ b ^ carry; //essentially, is the sum of bits odd?
        carry = ((a & b) | ((a ^ b) & carry)) << 1; //are exactly two of them 1?

        mask <<= 1; //move on to the next bit
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: not working. I checked it for 3 and 9 and got 12.
Also, it doesn't work for negative + positive.

Comment: Works for both positive and negative values, tested for more than 500 values

Comment: Fails on `-12` and `-8` if translated to python.

Answer (score 2):

this is in JavaScript, but here goes.

```
function add(number1,number2){
    var a = number1,b = number2,c;
    while(b != 0){
        c = a & b;
        a = a ^ b;
        b = c << 1;
    }
    return a;
}
```

here is an example
https://jsfiddle.net/Mythius/wum2huvu/4/

Comment: Could you prove that your method yields correct result?